# subview not showing in scrollview when using visual format constraint

Tags: ios, swift

I cannot understand why the blue view is not showing please take a look at my code. When i use `view.addSubView(mapView)` its shows in the main view but when I do `scrollView.addSubView(mapView)` it does not show.Everything appear to be correct with the constraint. I not sure why its not working.

```
import UIKit



class practiceViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var allConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

        let scrollView:UIScrollView = {
            let v = UIScrollView()
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return v
        }()

        let mapView:UIView = {
            let v = UIView()
            v.backgroundColor = .blue
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return v
        }()

        //views
        let views = [
            "scrollView":scrollView,
            "mapView":mapView
        ]
        //add views
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(mapView)

       // constraints
        let scrollviewHorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[scrollView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
        let scrollviewVerticleConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[scrollView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

        allConstraint += scrollviewVerticleConstraint
        allConstraint += scrollviewHorizontalConstraint

        let mapViewHorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[mapView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
        let mapViewVerticleConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[mapView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)

        allConstraint += mapViewHorizontalConstraint
        allConstraint += mapViewVerticleConstraint

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(allConstraint)
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens after adding: "H:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|" ?

Comment: @amalicka I updated the constraint to `let scrollviewHorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[scrollView]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)` and still the same same issue. the log does not display any error message either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapView needs a width and height. The scroll view doesn't know what the content size is until you set the size of your content so the scrollview defaults to zero. Try something like this instead:

```
let mapViewHorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[mapView(200)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
let mapViewVerticleConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[mapView(200)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
```